# Nuget dependency trigger doesn't work with Artifactory

Tags: teamcity, nuget, artifactory

We have a couple of project built as Nuget packages in our company. The last step of each build is to publish the package to the local Artifactory server, which serves as a Nuget repository.

If I have package B dependent on package A I want to trigger a build of B each time a new version of A appears in Artifactory. That's exactly what the [Nuget Dependency trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NuGet+Dependency+Trigger) is for. Only that it doesn't work.

I set Nuget package source to {`http://our-server-name/artifactory/api/nuget/my-feed-name/`} and Package-Id to A.

I get this error: 
Failed to check for package versions. Failed to check changes of A. Failed to parse output from NuGet feed. Check feed url: {`http://our-server-name/artifactory/api/nuget/my-feed-name/Packages()?%24filter=Id+eq+%27A%27`} is accessible

If I enter the reported URL to the browser, I can see the XML generated by Artifactory.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please post this issue to the teamcity tracker http://jetbrains.net/tracker/issues/TW. Please also attach Artifactory output (trancated if needed) to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [current list of open issues for nuget dependency trigger](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW?q=nuget%20dependency%20trigger%20State:%20Open%20Subsystem:%20%7Bplugin:%20NuGet%7D), perhaps someone has already reported it: